Amplify gen 2 table names
I have an Amplify gen 2 app and schema defined with Graphql for DynamoDb. Upon deployment, all tables are named with the format [Model]-[AppSyncId]-[Environment] e.g:

User-abcdefghijklmnop0123456789-NONE

For me, the [Environment] comes out as "NONE" regardless of whether it's a sandbox or the production deployment. I can't find gen 2 documentation that explains how this can be altered e.g. to PROD or Dev1Sandbox.
Has anyone achieved this?

To deploy to the sandbox environment, set the ENV environment variable to dev before running the npx ampx sandbox command.
ENV=dev

The CDK deployment process looks for this variable to determine the environment value.
When deploying through the Amplify build pipeline, ensure that the same ENV environment variable is set in the build agent as well. You can add this variable to the Amplify.yml file.

I am not sure, but this should work.


Thanks but I don't have a .env.local file, one wasn't created by the Amplify gen 2 project template. Can you find documentation as to the location/format/references to this file?

I have updated my answer @Jonny! .env.local was next.js specific, but that is not needed. Since, this variable is needed during deployment time, not when app is running.

Where would "ENV=dev" be stored locally for use by a sandbox? I tried under frontend/phases/build/commands but this didn't work. Also I added an environment variable for the deployed Amplify app under Hosting > Environment variables, called ENV with value PROD, but this hasn't altered the names of the dynamo tables after a redeploy

I added ENV=dev to my amplify.yml and it did not work unfortunately.
